# VBS If file is open

Tags: vbscript, inputbox

I've got a simple program than scans data into a spreadsheet along with a timestamp, then you can either update the data by saving, or quit and exit and save.

The only issue I've been stuck on for a day or so is to work around the error handling of the case of the spreadsheet being already open. Id like to have something like this;

if file is open THEn msgbox("File is open, close file and start again")
WScript.Quit

```
Option Explicit
DIM oFs: Set oFs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
DIM objExcel, strExcelPath, objSheet
DIM ib
DIM msg1
DIM msg2
strExcelPath = "c:\temp\Example.xls"
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.WorkBooks.Open strExcelPath
Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

DO 
ib=inputbox("SCAN NAME, SCAN LOTS"&vbCrLf&"TO UPDATE,SCAN ""UPDATE."""&vbCrLf&"TO EXIT, SCAN ""QUIT.""","Picklot Passout Database")
    IF ib="" THEN
    msg1=MsgBox("You must scan either a NAME or LOT NUMBER."&vbCrLf&"If you want to exit, scan QUIT."&vbCrLf&"Click OK to continue.",vbokonly,"Cannot Insert Blank Data")

    ELSEIF ib= "QUIT" OR ib= "quit" THEN
            objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
            objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
            objExcel.Application.Quit
            set objExcel = Nothing
            Set oFs = Nothing

        ELSEIF ib="update" OR ib="UPDATE" THEN
            objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
            msg2=MsgBox("Update Complete.",vbokonly,"Database Updated")
        ELSE
            objSheet.Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert
            objSheet.Cells(2, 1).Value = ib
            objSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value=(now)

            END IF


    LOOP WHILE NOT ib="quit" AND NOT ib="QUIT"
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? On the `objExcel.WorkBooks.Open strExcelPath` line? Another line? Please [edit] your question and paste that info.

Comment: No but if the excel file is open by another user or on same PC, it asks to save or overwrite data, nomatter what is clicked, it still doesn't save. The script only works when the excel file is not being viewed, so I was trying to figure out a way to let me know if it is open and to close it.

Answer (score 0):

This may help point you in the right direction. Sorry for the rushed, lowercase syntax and unconventional indentations (do not follow my bad practice - keep yours! :D), I wrote it in notepad you see - but it has been tested successfully.

Anyhow, with reference to your code, I have restructured it in a bad manner, familiar to me, adding the functionality you specify. Essentially the task manager application list is checked for a running instance of the "example" Excel file (depending on what version of excel you're using the syntax will differ).

If found it will make it the active window (thereby preventing a read only duplicate instance initiating). If no instance is found it will open "example.xlsx", in this case using a relative path to the script itself. A subroutine is then called to do the business with the cells...

I have written it in such a way to try keep your specs as well as maintain the "OK" and "Cancel" buttons explicitly functional. Please feel free to tinker with this, you may need to address the `path` and `instr` lines differently. I hope it helps! All the best.

```
path=createobject("scripting.filesystemobject").getparentfoldername(wscript.scriptfullname)
excelpath=path&"\example.xlsx"

set objword=createobject("word.application")
set coltasks=objword.tasks
i=0

for each objtask in coltasks
    name=lcase(objtask.name)
    if instr(name, "microsoft excel - example") then
    i=1
    end if
next

    if i=1 then
    wscript.echo "An active instance of ""example.xlsx"" has been found"
    set objexcel=getobject(excelpath)
    call UPDATER

    else
    set objexcel=createobject("excel.application")
    objexcel.workbooks.open(excelpath)
    set objsheet=objexcel.activeworkbook.worksheets(1)
    objexcel.visible=true   
    call UPDATER
    end if


sub UPDATER
do 
data=inputbox("Please enter data" &vbcrlf&vbcrlf& "To save data & continue, type ""update""" &vbcrlf& "To save data & exit, type ""quit""","Excel DB Updater")
    if isempty(data) then
    objexcel.activeworkbook.close
    objexcel.application.quit   
    wscript.quit()

    elseif lcase(data)="quit" then
    objexcel.activeworkbook.save
    objexcel.activeworkbook.close
    objexcel.application.quit
    quit=msgbox("DB Updating complete",vbokonly,"Excel DB  Updater")
    wscript.quit

    elseif lcase(data)="update" then
    objexcel.activeworkbook.save
    update=msgbox("Data save complete, press OK to continue",vbokonly,"Excel DB Updater")

    elseif len(data)<>0 then
    objsheet.range("A1").entirerow.insert
    objsheet.cells(1, 1).value=data
    objsheet.cells(1, 2).value=(now)
    add=msgbox("Data added, press OK to continue",vbokonly,"Excel DB Updater")
    end if
loop while len(data)>=0 and not lcase(data)="quit"
end sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a pretty good solution. I would just end up having to make visible=false just to hide it. Turns out since we upgraded everyone to office 2013 all PC's now have access database, so I wrote a script inputting directly into an access table that I created reporting functions on.. way easier dealing with data entry into access and\or sql server.. so that's the road I'm taking now.

I like the error handling and sub creation you did in this, this makes for a great template - I appreciate it!